# Asymptotic efficiency of modular multiplication

Tags: modular-arithmetic, complexity

What is the best known asymptotic/concrete complexity of modular multiplication?

Using Montgomery multiplication, if $M(n)$ is the cost of one integer multiplication of $n$ bits, then the cost is $2M(n)+o(M(n))$ (assuming comparisons and bit-shifts are $o(M(n))$. Is this the best known?

Comment: Do you care about the time needed for calculating the two Montgomery constants?

Comment: No; I'm thinking about algorithms/circuits that are "precompiled" for a specific modulus

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be the case for generic moduli $n$ and generic exponents. See the preprint of a chapter entitled "Efficient Modular Multiplication" (available [here](https://eprint.iacr.org/2021/1151.pdf)) from the book *Computational Cryptography* edited by Joppe W. Bos and Martijn Stam and published by Cambridge University Press, 2021.

There are efficiencies of various tweaks discussed in there in terms of parallelization, latency and area.

Answer (score 0):

[McLaughlin's modular multiplication](https://doi.org/10.1090/S0025-5718-03-01543-6) computes $AB/(2^n-1) \bmod N$ in time $O(1.5M(n))$ in the FFT range.